# How to call mutiple function at the same time without waiting for function completed

Tags: python, async-await

I want to write a code to ping multiple IPs at the same time. The function is as following:

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

IPs = {"google": "8.8.8.8",
       "google2":"8.8.4.4",
       "cloudflare": "1.1.1.1",
        "cloudflare2":"1.0.0.1"
       } # not fixed length, different number of IPs each time

def pinghost(name, host):
    print(f"start ping {name} - {host}")
    cmd = ["ping", host]
    ping_reply = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    print(ping_reply)
    print(f"end ping {name} - {host}")

def main(IPs):
    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for i in IPs:
        print(i, IPs[i])
        p.apply_async(func=pinghost(i, IPs[i]))
    p.close()
    p.join()

main(IPs)
```

Even though I used apply_async, looks like it's still waiting for ping these IPs one by one.

```
google 8.8.8.8
start ping google - 8.8.8.8
b'\r\nPinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=116\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=116\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=116\r\nReply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=116\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 8.8.8.8:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 12ms, Maximum = 23ms, Average = 15ms\r\n'
end ping google - 8.8.8.8
google2 8.8.4.4
start ping google2 - 8.8.4.4
b'\r\nPinging 8.8.4.4 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 8.8.4.4: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=116\r\nReply from 8.8.4.4: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=116\r\nReply from 8.8.4.4: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=116\r\nReply from 8.8.4.4: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=116\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 8.8.4.4:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 14ms, Average = 11ms\r\n'
end ping google2 - 8.8.4.4
cloudflare 1.1.1.1
start ping cloudflare - 1.1.1.1
b'\r\nPinging 1.1.1.1 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=8ms TTL=58\r\nReply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=58\r\nReply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=58\r\nReply from 1.1.1.1: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=58\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 1.1.1.1:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 5ms, Maximum = 14ms, Average = 9ms\r\n'
end ping cloudflare - 1.1.1.1
cloudflare2 1.0.0.1
start ping cloudflare2 - 1.0.0.1
b'\r\nPinging 1.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:\r\nReply from 1.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=58\r\nReply from 1.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=58\r\nReply from 1.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=58\r\nReply from 1.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=58\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 1.0.0.1:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 13ms, Average = 11ms\r\n'
end ping cloudflare2 - 1.0.0.1
```

So how can I ping these IPs at the same time？（call the function at the same time and don't wait for the result）

I also tried aysncio, the same, it ping IPs one by one.

```
async def pinghost(name, host):
    print(f"start ping {name} - {host}")
    cmd = ["ping", host]
    ping_reply = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    print(ping_reply)
    print(f"end ping {name} - {host}")

async def main(IPs):
    for i in IPs:
        print(i)
        await pinghost(i, IPs[i])

asyncio.run(main(IPs))
```

Comment: Consider using the threading module https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Your code is relatively simple so it wouldnt surprise me if it finished before a new thread had had chance to initialize and start

Comment: @AndyKnight, thanks, looks like threading works.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested by Andy, use threading works.

```
def pinghost(name, host):
    print(f"start ping {name} - {host}")
    cmd = ["ping", host]
    ping_reply = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
    print(ping_reply)
    print(f"end ping {name} - {host}")

def main(IPs):
    threads = list()
    for i in IPs:
        x = threading.Thread(target=pinghost, args=(i, IPs[i]))
        threads.append(x)
        x.start()
```

I found here is tricky, at beginning I was using

```
        x = threading.Thread(target=pinghost(i, IPs[i]))
```

It's not working, must use

```
        x = threading.Thread(target=pinghost, args=(i, IPs[i]))
```